# Redis Desktop Manager Shows duplicate key

Tags: redis, desktop

Does anyone run into the issue of dupe key of Redis Desktop Manager?
[image: duplicate redis key in redis desktop manager]

I used the redis CLI to checked my redis server, everything is fine. So apparently sth wrong with the desktop manager.

I am using the destop manager in Windows 2016 Server.
My redis is hosted in aws. It is a 4 node cluster.

[image]

Comment: Maybe they are different, but longer than the line you see here?

Comment: It may be as well problems in SCAN command against a cluster. Docs says it tries to show all keys, but consistency is not guaranteed.

Comment: Any update on this?  I am seeing the same thing once I changed to cluster mode.   Haven't tried a client yet to see if any issues there